# How can skype sounds be changed, since the 5 version?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype

In the skype 4.3 sounds were in the `/usr/share/skype/sounds` folder (**Ubuntu 16.04**). I could replace the `CallRingingIn.wav` file to another and change the ringtone this way. But in the new skype (since the 5 version), I can't do this - the `/usr/share/skypeforlinux` folder doesn't contain sound files.

I also checked the `/home/minimax/.config/skypeforlinux/` - there are not sound files, too.

**Skype version:** 8.18.0.6

**Question 1:** Does the changing of sounds possible in the new skype and how it can be done?

The problem I want to solve in real are next: some music files (including those played online, like youtube) has low loudness, so it needed to increase overall system loudness, while playing these files, and if a skype call happens in this moment, it hits to the ears. So, I change the `CallRingingIn.wav` to its copy with the lowered by 10-20% loudness and the problem is solved.

**Question 2:** How do you solve this kind of problems?

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Skype use PulseAudio, which allows you to set audio volume levels on a per-application basis. Rather than trying to change sounds in the `skypeforlinux` installation, I would suggest you use that.

To access per-application volume settings, run `pavucontrol`.